# textInput doesn't get re-rendered when state changes

Tags: react-native

I currently have this function which renders a textInput with a different placeholder for each state:

```
_renderSimpleForm = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.simpleContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={[styles.textContentWhite, styles.textContentWhiteHeight, styles.indentLeft]}
          placeholder={this.state.form.userInput}
          placeholderTextColor="#B7BEDE"
          onChangeText={(userInputValue) => 
            //TODO: Saving text to nested userInput is causing problem, temporarily save it to userInputValue
            //this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, userInput: text}}
            this.setState({userInputValue}
              )}
          //onSubmitEditing={this._submitInfo()}
        />
        <View style={styles.whiteLine}/>
      </View>
      );
  }
```

However each time after the state changes, the value from the previous state is still there in the textInput. I thought this textInput would get re-rendered with the new placeHolder value when the state changes. What am I doing wrong here?

My state object is as below:

```
const states = {
  //TODO: including GPA and coursework
  schoolForm: {
    prompt: "Where did you go to school?",
    userInput: "School name",
  },
  durationForm: {
    prompt: "For how long?",
    userInput: "Duration",
  },
  degreeForm: {
    prompt: "What was your degree?",
    userInput: "Degree",
  },
  majorForm: {
    prompt: "What did you study?",
    userInput: "Major",
  },
}

export default class NewEducation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //form: states.reviewForm,
      form: states.schoolForm,
      userInputs: {
        schoolName: "",
        duration: "",
        degree: "",
        major: "",
        GPA: "",
        coursework: "",
      },
      //for testing
      userInputValue: "",
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `placeholder={this.state.form.userInput}` is referring to a different value than the updated state `onChangeText={(userInputValue) =>  this.setState({userInputValue})}`

Try this `this.setState({form: { ...this.state.form, userInput: userInputValue }} )}`

Your function should now look like this:

```
<TextInput
    style={[styles.textContentWhite, styles.textContentWhiteHeight, styles.indentLeft]}
    placeholder={this.state.form.userInput}
    placeholderTextColor="#B7BEDE"
    onChangeText={(userInputValue) =>
    this.setState({form: { ...this.state.form, userInput: userInputValue }} )}
  />
```

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion and the textInput disappears once I start typing in, with no error message in the console at all...

Comment: how does your state object look like? based on your placeholder code, it seems like it has a property of this kind: form: { userInput: ' ' } in which case it should work as I just tested it

Comment: Hi I posted my state object above

Comment: It's weird the textInput still disappears once I start typing in, also with no error message...

Comment: It must be an additional issue because the form itself should now display. I created a test example myself with this.state = { form: { userInput: 'test', prompt: 'test2' } } and the TextInput is woking fine

Comment: Please check your styles object I see styles.textContentWhite in there it could be making your text white which might appear as if though the input is disappearing

Comment: My background is dark blue so I don't think that's the case. Also the submit button would get pushed up so it seems like the textInput just vanished from the DOM

Comment: Well then you have additional mistakes somewhere else in your code which I can't see because you only posted part of your code...

Comment: I think you started a chat yesterday and I sent you my code. Do you still have access to it?